# JQuery UI ButtonSet fails on copied HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<div id="TabTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <span id="tab_radios">
        <input type="radio" id="tab_l1" name="layout"/>  
        <label for="tab_l1">1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="tab_l2" name="layout" checked="checked" />  
        <label for="tab_l2">2</label>
    </span>
</div>

<div id="RealTab">
</div>

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

// copy tab_radios's html from TabTemplate to RealTab
$('#RealTab').html(replaceAll('tab_', 'tab1_', $('#TabTemplate').html()));
$('#tab1_radios').buttonset();
$('#tab1_radios :input').change(function() { alert("click"); });
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PEcX9/2/) (simplified out of a much larger code)

My HTML contain a hidden TemplateTab div with radio buttons and an empty RealTab div

First I copy the inner HTML from TemplateTab to RealTab and replace all tab_ to tab1_ in ids labels etc

I then call buttonset() on the tab1_radios and attach a change event

However clicking on the buttons causes JQuery exception "cannot call methods on button prior to initialization" - why ??

Note that removing the buttonset() call produce a (ugly) radio buttons which handle the event fine.

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

radioGroup() picks up everything that share the name of a radio button, so you need to change the name's of the newly created radio inputs.

this is a working fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/PEcX9/17/ -- for a proof of concept but im sure you can find a cleaner way to do it :)

```
    function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
      return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
   }

    // copy tab_radios's html from TabTemplate to RealTab
    $('#RealTab').html(replaceAll('tab_', 'tab1_', $('#TabTemplate').html()));

   //change the names of the radio inputs
   $('#tab_l1').attr('name', 'layout1');
   $('#tab_l2').attr('name', 'layout1');
   $('#tab1_radios').buttonset();
   $('#tab1_radios :input').change(function() { alert("click"); });
```

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8761